# Excel VBA Application Sum

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a sum on a column using VBA and in doing so any variation of Application.Sum is resulting in incorrect output.

Somewhere I read that this issue might occur if my datatype is considered as text, so I updated the whole column to be Number, yet my issue with case 1 persisted.

```
'Case 1 - Incorrect result @ 15.67 for a whole column of 341 1's
ActiveSheet.Range("L1").Value = Application.Sum(Range("E1").EntireColumn)

'Case 2 - Returns correct result @ 341
ActiveSheet.Range("L2").Formula = "=sum(E:E)"
```

Can someone please explain why the output in Case 1 is incorrect compared to Case 2 which is a straightforward code

Comment: Which module is that code in?

Comment: The code is one sheet, whereas the sum is happening on another sheet. On top of the above snippet, I'm activating the sheet where I want to sum the column. Does that result in the Case 1 issue?

Comment: Avoid using `ActiveSheet`. This is because at any given point the **ActiveSheet** might not be the sheet you want to reference. Qualify your sheet (i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1").Value = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E1").EntireColumn)`). Or you could use the `With` clause to reduce the length of the statement

Comment: If the code is in a worksheet module, then `Range("E1")` refers to a cell on the sheet containing the code. Either use `ActiveSheet.Range("E1")` or specify the sheet by name if you can.